# How can I remain in the same page after refresh in Angular 15?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular14

Working with Angular15
I want to remain in the same page after hard refresh in the browser

I have **APP_BASE_HREF** config in app.module.ts

I have an routing url
For eg: `localhost:4200/app/page1`  - Here **app** is *baseHref*  This is working when I refresh

For eg: `localhost:4200/app/page2/:paramter`  - Here **app** is *baseHref*  This is always navigating to the previous page

I tried with {provide: LocationStrategy: useClass: PathLocationStrategy} but still same issue

How can i fix this?

Comment: you wrote `paramter`(not `parameter` -see the `e`) -I don't know if it's a type when you wrote the question-